# Contact force to air pressure ratio

Tags: forces, drag, aerodynamics

#### Preamble

Just to preface, I am not a physicist or physics student. So my question is not related to any real world application or projects. It is more of a shower thought than anything else. Therefore, it may sound silly or I am not providing enough information, but it has piqued my interest for some reason.

#### Question

My question concerns the level of force a moving object exerts on another object compared to the force of the air molecules being displaced on the same object. For example, if I swing a knife down on a block, the "wind" of the strike is hitting it too. I want to know how many orders of magnitude greater the direct contact force of the knife is on the block than the air pressure.

From my understanding of what a physicist told me, the air pressure force can at most be equal to the drag of said object. So if I wanted to find a minimum ratio, I would first find the drag and divide it from the force (F = m*a). I wasn't able to verify this any where, so I thought I'd ask here.

With that said, what would be some generalized values for these objects if we were to assume normal air conditions and typical sizes for objects?

- Fist in a "punching" motion
- Hand + forearm in a "chopping" motion
- Sword (ex: katana) in a "swinging" motion